# How to specify an ajax call for PHP part handling

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using ajax calls for getting information from php files and I am new to these. I have 7 elemnts in my html to be clicked and fire an ajax call. I created 7 different php files to do stuff for these ajax calls, like that:

*html part:*

```
<a style="cursor:pointer;" id="one"></a>
<a style="cursor: pointer;" id="two"></a>
<a style="cursor: pointer;" id="three">></a>
       .
       .
       .   // 7 elements goes on like this.
```

*javascript part:*

```
$("#one").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
       url: '../one.php',
       dataType: 'html',
       success: function(result){
        var res = (result).replace( /^\D+/g, '');
        switch(res) {
        case '1':
        window.location.href = "http://www.......com";
        break;
        case '2':
        alert('hgjgkj');
        break;
        }}
    });});
```

And 7 java parts for each element. Then 7 php part for each element.
What I am asking is that if there is any way to handle these calls in just one php file.
(For example assigning a name, variable or id to the ajax call and check in php file which call is it).
Like that (in php):

```
if(the call from html_element_one){
// do stuff
}
elseif(the call from html_element_two){
// do stuff
}
...and goes on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that simply adding class to all elements and use one function;

```
<a style="cursor:pointer;" id="one" class="ajax"></a>
<a style="cursor: pointer;" id="two" class="ajax"></a>
<a style="cursor: pointer;" id="three" class="ajax">></a>
.....



$(".ajax").on("click"i function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "common.php?type=" + $(this).attr("id"),
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(response) {
            // handle response
        }
    })
});
```

**common.php**

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_GET["type"])) {
        // your code here
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function ajaxAction(number){
$.ajax({
   url: '../action.php',
   data:{option:number}
   dataType: 'html',
   success: function(result){
         .......
    }} 
});
$("#one").click(function(){  
    ajaxAction('one');
});
```

And PHP(../action.php)

```
$option=$_REQUEST["option"];
switch(option) {
    case 'one':
         .......
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this but a simple one would be to simplify your code with a class selector like this:

```
<a style="cursor:pointer;" class='ajax-link' id="one" data-variable='1'></a>
<a style="cursor:pointer;" class='ajax-link' id="two" data-variable='2'></a>
```

And then in your JS:

```
$('.ajax-link').click(function() {
  var variable = $(this).data('variable');
  .ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "single-php-file.php",
    data: { variable: variable, anotherVar: "Whatever you want" }
  })
  .done(function(response) {
    alert("The PHP file returned: "+response);
  });
});
```

And then in your PHP, something like:

```
<?php
   $variable = $_POST['variable'];
   if ($variable == 1) {

   }
   if ($variable == 2) {

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, use [delegated events](https://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of direct attached events

Second, pass the clicked id/class to the PHP script:

```
$("#one").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
       url: '../ajax.php?clickedButton=' + this.id,
```

Third, parse the param by PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET['clickedButton'])) {
    switch($_GET['clickedButton']) {
        case 'one':
           /* ... */
           break;
    }
}
```